# ChromeDriver 79 under Selenium needs HTTPS certificate manually accepted every time

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ssl-certificate, selenium-chromedriver, codeception

I've just updated my ChromeDriver from version 78 to version 79. Now Chrome gives me a warning on all my tests and fails if I don't add the certificate as an exception in time (a have a few seconds before the test fails). I didn't have to do anything special to ChromeDriver 78, it just worked.

[image]

How can I get ChromeDriver 79 to work without manual intervention?

Comment: What does the warning says? Which certificate?

Comment: @DebanjanB See update.

Comment: set 'acceptInsecureCerts' to true and then try

Comment: @RahulL Where? How?

Comment: which language binding are you using ? java?

Comment: @RahulL PHP with Codeception.

Comment: In desired capabilities set it to true. something like this $this->desiredCapabilities->setCapability('acceptInsecureCerts',true)

Comment: @RahulL Thanks! It goes in the `.yml` file under `capabilities:`. Any idea why this is not necessary for ChromeDriver 78?

Comment: Not sure about the difference in 78 & 79 related to ssl

Answer (score 0):

`DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true);
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);`